# At what stage is @SpringBootApplication executed in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When writing a Spring Boot application, we have code like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Which means, it can run as a standalone application(having `main` method) - so far, so good.

My doubt starts here:

The `main` would be invoked by  JVM, so it will see main method, and then execute the line:

```
 SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

Then, who does check the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`  - is it interpreted on-the-fly once control goes into Spring framework when JVM executes the first line?

Comment: Yes, everything happens in `run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out as well...

Your class `Application` is the 'main' class.  It is calling a static method on `SpringApplication`.

It is the `SpringApplication` class that actually starts the entire Spring Boot process and all the code that will check for the Spring Annotations and things like that.

I have never looked at the code behind that class, but it has to be tremendous.

Comment: So, if my application doesn't have this annotation - will it simply be a plain Java application, and probably, won't even become a RESTful all (assuming it has REST controllers)

Comment: I do not know.  My guess is one of two things will happen.  The first, is er, well, nothing.  The second is that an exception will be thrown.  Give it a try and let us know what happens.  :D

Comment: The answer is...  It basically does nothing.  Spring Boot will show its banner and the following error message:  `Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.`

Comment: I needed to remember this myself, `@SpringBootApplication` is the combination of the following three annotations: `@Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration, and @ComponentScan`.  Just adding the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation is enough to let the application start with out any error messages.  Nothing happens, but it starts and runs.